# How to change className in external lib in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rev-slider in my project. It generates me slider, everything works. However I need the root container to have `class="tp-container rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container"`. I am not sure how can I set that className? I opened the source (react-rev-slider/src/ReactRevSlider.js:18) and I see that className="tp-container" is set. No way to set the classes I need. How can I deal with that? Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot set the class on the created element, the only other options appears to be to place the element inside an element with the respective classes. You could also file an issue/make a PR to allow setting the class name.

Comment: thanks, this helps, root element class worked